# Determine overall ratio from individual ratios

Tags: statistics, divisibility, ratio

I have a set of statistics that I need to find the overall ratio to.
This example will work with only two items so I'll write them down:

```
 A  |  B
---------
12  |  5
 6  |  2
```

The total ratio needs to be worked out as: `(12 + 6) / (5 + 2)`
Which is `2.57`

The problem however, is that the ratio of each row can be modified by a user, meaning the source values A and B can only be used as "default" sources.

To allow partial modification of the entire set by modifying specific ratios I saved the ratios of each individual row like this:

```
 A  |  B  | R
-------------
12  |  5  | 2.4
 6  |  2  | 3
```

I then attempted to come to the same overall ratio (since at the moment these ratios are un-modified), however getting the mean average did not work:

```
(2.4 + 3) / 2 = 2.7
```

The fact that the ratios can be modified make the original source data completely irrelevant in the overall statistic, but I still need to arrive at `2.57`, is this possible?

I am prepared to change the type of modifiable information stored against each row, providing it can still be used to represent a percentage.

Answer (score 2):

I dont understand programming, but  what I can tell you is  $\frac{a+b}{c+d} \neq \frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}}{2}$, that is why it didn't work. What you can do is may be, try $\frac{a+b}{c+d}=\frac{\frac{a}{b}+1}{\frac{c}{d}+1}.\frac{b}{d}$.

In you example $a=12,b=6,c=5,d=2$ which will give you $2.57$

Comment: That actually works really well `$x = ((($a / $b) + 1) / (($c / $d) + 1)) * ($b / $d);`, I'm just trying to test it on a third row now.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, because it depends on `b` and `d` as being true after the modification.  Since the use case I'm working with deals with an indeterminate modifier I'll have to write this off as impossible.  Still I gave you +1, I don't know how you thought of that algorithm :)